Transplanting Watermelons when fruit start to appear
I made the mistake of planting my watermelons in medium size flower pots, now the fruit is starting to form can I transplant them into bigger bots some of my melons are the size of a grapefruit. Can I put them in bigger pots or is it to late.

+1 How did it work out for You? I was about to write an answer but then saw the question is 1 month old already.

Watermelons can be sensitive to changes in light (and damaged roots can make plants extra sensitive to light). If you don't want to keep them in that pot, I'd recommend giving them some potassium (no nitrogen), and cutting the plant back to a few to several leaves (even if you have to cut the fruits off) before the transplant. I'm guessing it would grow more vigorously and set new fruits if you did that. I could be wrong.
If you want to keep the fruits that are currently on it, you might as well just keep it in the same pot and fertilize it well.

Watermelons, like most other cucurbits, are notorious for disliking any meddling with their roots. I would personally leave the vines alone - trying to transplant them now would be a mistake at this degree of maturity.

I guess as you said, the fruit is starting to form now it's not a good time to transplant it as it will be more risky although it is not impossible to do. Majorly you can check this thing
That is your plant is getting limited or struggling then the transplanting risk can be worth but you have to take some careful steps so that the plant doesn't goes under stress.
If the plant seems to be healthy and producing food properly then you might avoid transplanting just giving attention to optimal care to the current pot like feeding, regular watering, balancing fertilizer, and making sure that the plant is getting enough sunlight.
In case you decide to transplant some measures I would like to recommend you are
First Choose the right size of the pot as the watermelon plant needs good enough space to grow with good drainage.
Secondly, fill the pot with well-draining potting mix adding some compost or balanced fertilizer for nutrient maintenance
Thirdly, Watering the plant before transplanting will help in easy removal from the old pot and will also reduce the transplant shock.
Fourth, While transplanting be careful with the roots and developing fruit tapping on the plant sides and gently pulling the plant by holding the stem base.
Fifth, Fill in around the roots with soil gently firm the soil around the base, and water the plant properly after transplanting to keep the soil moist but don't waterlog it. Also, place the plant in a sunny spot.
Risks that your plant can face after transplanting will be that it can go under transplant shock which can lead to stunted growth, dropping fruit, or plant death. The roots may also get damaged which can affect the ability of the plant to take up water and nutrients. So, take the decision responsibility

Not so sure about "pulling the plant by holding the stem base" or putting the plant right into sun.
